# Imitating 'ppoints' R function in python

Tags: python, r

The `R` *ppoints* function is described as:

```
Ordinates for Probability Plotting

Description:

     Generates the sequence of probability points ‘(1:m - a)/(m +
     (1-a)-a)’ where ‘m’ is either ‘n’, if ‘length(n)==1’, or
     ‘length(n)’.

Usage:

     ppoints(n, a = ifelse(n <= 10, 3/8, 1/2))
...
```

I've been trying to replicate this function in `python` and I have a couple of doubts.

1- The first `m` in `(1:m - a)/(m + (1-a)-a)` is always an integer: `int(n)` (ie: the *integer* of `n`) if `length(n)==1` and `length(n)` otherwise.

2- The second `m` in the same equation is **NOT** an integer if `length(n)==1` (it assumes the real value of `n`) and it **IS** an integer (`length(n)`) otherwise.

3- The `n` in `a = ifelse(n <= 10, 3/8, 1/2)` is the **real** number `n` if `length(n)==1` and the **integer** `length(n)` otherwise.

This points are not made clear at all in the description and I'd very much appreciate if someone could confirm that this is the case.

---

### Add

Well this was initially posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ because I was hoping to get the input of staticians who work with the `ppoints` function. Since it has been migrated here, I'll paste below the function I wrote to replicate `ppoints` in `python`. I've tested it and both seem to give back the same results, but I'd be great if someone could clarify the points made above because they are not made at all clear by the function's description.

```
def ppoints(vector):
    '''
    Mimics R's function 'ppoints'.
    '''

    m_range = int(vector[0]) if len(vector)==1 else len(vector)

    n = vector[0] if len(vector)==1 else len(vector)
    a = 3./8. if n <= 10 else 1./2

    m_value =  n if len(vector)==1 else m_range
    pp_list = [((m+1)-a)/(m_value+(1-a)-a) for m in range(m_range)]

    return pp_list
```

Comment: Obvious question: presumably you copied/ported the actual, very simple,  `R` code for `ppoints`, so what happens when you run your python version -- do you get the same values or not?  And have you read the material in the references listed on `?ppoints` ?

Comment: Actually I drafted the code from scratch based on the description in `?ppoints` and checking the results given by `ppoints` in R with the same set of floats. It hadn't occurred to me to look at the R code for the function... Perhaps I should just do that.

Comment: @Gabriel you copied one usecase; in genral, a is a paramether, not an expression `3./8. if n <= 10 else 1./2`

Comment: Yes @alko, I know. I just copied the default case which is the one I'll be using.

Comment: @Gabriel in general, your code is ok, there are some minor comments: it seems that in `R` (I am not familiar with it) len(n)=1 for scalars, so you have to handle this differently in python. second, your code don't deal well (in py2) with integer params, you need to convert them to float. Everything else seems ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would implement this with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
def ppoints(n, a):
    """ numpy analogue or `R`'s `ppoints` function
        see details at http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ppoints.html 
        :param n: array type or number"""
    try:
        n = np.float(len(n))
    except TypeError:
        n = np.float(n)
    return (np.arange(n) + 1 - a)/(n + 1 - 2*a)
```

Sample output:

```
>>> ppoints(5, 1./2)
array([ 0.1,  0.3,  0.5,  0.7,  0.9])
>>> ppoints(5, 1./4)
array([ 0.13636364,  0.31818182,  0.5       ,  0.68181818,  0.86363636])
>>> n = 10
>>> a = 3./8. if n <= 10 else 1./2
>>> ppoints(n, a)
array([ 0.06097561,  0.15853659,  0.25609756,  0.35365854,  0.45121951,
        0.54878049,  0.64634146,  0.74390244,  0.84146341,  0.93902439])
```

One can use [R fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=37zmhMyE&version=2) to test implementation.